# Cones and Dot Product

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let $V$ = {$v_1$, $v_2$,......,$v_k$} be a collection of $k$ vectors in $R^n$. Prove that a vector $z$ in $R^n$ is not in the cone of $V$ if and only if there is a vector $w$ in $R^n$ such that $z$ is less than $90$ degrees from $w$ but every $v_i$ in $V$ is at least $90$ degrees from $w$.**

I know that $z$ would be in the cone of $v$ if and only if $z=\sum _{m=0}^k\:x_iv_i$, where all $x_i$ are a set of non-negative numbers. I also see that it is being implied here that the dot product of $w$ and $z$ is greater than $0$ and the dot product of all $v_i$ and $z$ is less than $0$.

But I am not sure how to proceed further than this. I was thinking about utilizing the distributive property of the dot product and how it would lead to a contradiction if the above condition holds. But I am not entirely sure on how to proceed.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Prove the contrapositive.

Suppose that $z = \sum x_iv_i$ for $x_i$ non negative. Let $w$ be a vector such that every $v_i$ has an angle of at least $90^\circ$ with $w$. This implies that $v_i \cdot w \leq 0$ for all $i$.

Now,
$$
z \cdot w =\left(\sum x_iv_i \right)\cdot w =  \sum x_i (v_i \cdot w) \leq 0
$$

because each term $x_i(v_i \cdot w)$ is a product of a $+$ and a $-$ term, so is non-negative. Therefore, there is no way that $z$ can be less than $90^\circ $ from $w$.

Therefore, no such $w$ as mentioned in the question exists.